# How to get facebook profile picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am Ruby on Rails developer.

I am using omniauth with devise to facebook authentication.

How I can fetch the facebook profile picture.

Please give me needful help.

Answer (score 1):

You can `raise` the response using `raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml` to see the information provided by facebook in your **omniauth_callbacks_controller**.
You have to do save this in your db to save user facebook picture :

```
auth.info.image
```

Comment: you can use request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml to see the information provided by any provider like facebook, twitter etc.